# Check and clear any open divs with a particular class inside the container

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check and clear any `div`s with the class `demoForm` that are inside the `div` container. The `demoForm` `div`s are hidden by default when the page loads, but appear when a user clicks the `addUser` link. It can appear at several places, since the link is available at several places.

Before a new one is added, I'd like to clear any existing ones inside the container which may have been generated by a user before.

I presently do:

```
$(".addUser").click(function(){
        $('.demoForm').hide();
    });
```

How can I use an if else or something like that to check only for open ones and close them, instead of simply doing like I did.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Generated by Edit Plus</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/site/css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/site/scripts/jQueryCore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".addUser").click(function(){
        $('.demoForm').hide();
    });
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.toolOptions{
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="addUser">Add a new user</div>

    <div class="demoForm">
    I'm the form div.
    </div>

    <div class="demoForm">
    I'm the form div.
    </div>

    <div class="demoForm">
    I'm the form div
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"How can I use an if else or something like that to check only for open ones and close them, instead of simply doing like I did."* What's wrong about your solution? What is it about it you want to change? I mean, you *could* use the `:visible` pseudo-selector, but there's no good reason to if you don't want any of them to remain visible.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There's nothing wrong, it's just that it didn't seem correct to me. Setting all of them to hide even if they were not hidden.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder My code sets all of them to hidden. Not just the visible ones.

Comment: @ jmenezes: Sure, but it's harmless to do so. Whereas the `:visible` pseudo-selector, because it's implemented by jQuery rather than by your browser, slows down the lookup for the elements. Now, if you have only a small number of elements, it's not like that matters, but hiding an element that's already hidden is completely harmless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use If else statement here. You can easily do this with `:visaible`

For example

```
$(".addUser").click(function(){
    $('.demoForm:visible').hide();
});
```

OR

```
$(".addUser").click(function(){
    if($('.demoForm').is(':visible')){
      $('.demoForm').hide();
    }
});
```

OR

```
$(".addUser").click(function(){        
    if($('.container').find('.demoForm').is(':visible')){
      $('.container').find('.demoForm').hide();
    }
});
```

OR

```
$(".addUser").click(function(){
    $('.container').find('.demoForm:visible').hide();
});
```

Comment: Any idea why I get the error I posted when using your second and third example?

Comment: You are using "jQueryCore.js", if you want then download the higher or latest version of jquery and then use the provided code...

Comment: It's still the same with the very latest version of jQuery. Maybe your code is wrong?

Comment: @jmenezes `is()` returns a boolean value, what you want is `filter()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can selects all divs that are visible using [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) selector and hide them only:-

```
$(".addUser").click(function () {
    $('.demoForm:visible').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

```
$(".addUser").click(function(){
    $('.demoForm:visible').hide();
});
```